# Upload de arquivos em c# para API

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-azure

Olá! Estava enviando arquivos fazendo `POST` para o Azure DevOps ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)) via JavaScript (apenas para testar algumas funcionalidades):

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

request.send(file);
```

Por motivos de segurança estava migrando isso para métodos do lado do servidor, no qual estou usando c#. Cheguei até esse ponto:

```cs
//criando o request
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
//headers
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationBasic);
request.Headers.Add("20", "application/json"); //20 = accept
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = 0;
//body
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream = file.InputStream;
dataStream.Close();
//fazendo o request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

// le o conteudo da resposta
using (Stream dataStreamResp = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResp);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Eu já estou consumindo a API ok. Recebo no retorno status 200 e a url do arquivo que fiz upload como esperado, porém ao abrir a url da resposta ela está toda em branco, ou seja, não está enviando o arquivo, apenas seu nome.

Sei que, de acordo com a documentação, preciso de colocar no `body` uma `string` com o `Stream para upload`, porém não sei fazer isso e não tive muito sucesso também pesquisando pela internet...

Obrigado!

Comment: geralmente no seu dataStream se utilizaria o .write() pra escrever o conteudo a ser subido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui! O problema estava no óbvio, eu precisava definir o tamanho do `contentLength`. Eu pensava que se eu setasse ele para 0, significaria que não teria tamanho definido, mas não é o caso. Segue o código:

```cs
//criando o request
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
//headers
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationBasic);
request.Headers.Add("20", "application/json"); //20 = accept
request.Method = "POST";

//mudando o body
request.ContentLength = file.InputStream.Length;
using(Stream streamRequest = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    file.InputStream.CopyTo(streamRequest);
}

//fazendo o request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

//Pega o response
using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que você não troca o `WebRequest` pelo `WebClient`, utilizando-o desta forma:

```
using (WebClient WC = new WebClient())
{
    WC.UploadFileCompleted += UploadCompleted;
    WC.UploadProgressChanged += UploadProgress;
    WC.Headers.Add("name", "value.."); // headers..
    WC.Headers.Add("name", "value.."); // headers..

    WC.UploadFile("API", @"diretório do arquivo ao ser enviando.. (C:\Users\...\Desktop\....)");
}
```

```
private void UploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // ação após o envio ser completado..
}

private void UploadProgress(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ação durante o envio do arquivo..
}
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação [WebClient.UploadFile Método da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=net-5.0). Fora a utilização do `UploadFileAsync` e/ou `UploadFileTaskAsync` para trabalhar de forma assíncrona. Espero que o tenha ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar aqui

Comment: No "@"diretório do arquivo ao ser enviando.. (C:\Users\...\Desktop\....)" como eu faria? Porque eu estou recebendo o arquivo como um parâmetro, não está armazenado em nenhum diretório

Comment: que parâmetro é esse? é um base64 ou byte?

Comment: é um objeto `HttpPostedFile` que posso transformar em um objeto do tipo `Stream`

Comment: Acredito que você precisará salvar esse conteúdo `Stream` ou `Byte` para o diretório, exemplo: arquivo.pdf para *"C:\Users\...\Desktop\arquivo.pdf"* ai na linha: *@"diretório do arquivo ao ser enviando.. (C:\Users\...\Desktop\....)"* você coloca o diretório... Deixa-me ver se encontro uma documentação referente a esse tipo de ação em C#

Comment: Encontrei essas duas opções aqui [HttpPostedFile.InputStream Propriedade](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream?view=netframework-4.8) e [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c) vê se consegue resolver, só não lhe auxilio mais devido eu está numa correria!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui aqui, era mais simples do que pensava kkkkkkkkkkkk vou colocar a resposta